# Issues with dynamic React element creation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Disclaimer... this might turn into more of a specific js question (relating to dynamically accessing object properties using variables) ...

I am attempting to create a dynamically rendered menu where a menu schema is passed in (testinputs) and that menu is rendered complete with routing.

There are two parts to this:

1. rendering the menu itself
2. rending the routes

This question is about rendering the routes.

```
import DataGrid from "./DataGrid.js"
import AddItem from "./AddItem.js"

const AllMenuItems = {
  "DataGrid":DataGrid
  "AddItem":AddItem,
}

const testinput = {
  data: [
    {
      name: "DataGrid",
      url: "/datagrid",
    },
    {
      name: "Transact",
      children: [
        {
          name: "AddItem",
          url: "/additem",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

I have a function expression that utilizes jsx to return a specific dynamic route...

Rendering works when I hard code the component prop like so, referencing the imported React component directly...

```
<Route path={url} component={AddItem}/>
```

But when I attempt to do things dynamically (see below) the routing doesn't work.

```
const routeBuilder = (children) => {
    return children.map((subOption) => {
      if (!subOption.children) {
        var name = subOption.name;
        var url = subOption[url];
        var MyComponent = AllMenuItems[name];    
        return (
          <Route path={url} component={MyComponent}/>
        );
      }
      routeBuilder(subOption.children);
    })
  }
```

What am I overlooking here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is recursive `routeBuilder` return values are not used.

Some thing like

```
const routeBuilder = (children) => {
    return children.map((subOption) => {
      if (!subOption.children) {
        var name = subOption.name;
        var url = subOption[url];
        var MyComponent = AllMenuItems[name];    
        return (
          <Route path={url} component={MyComponent}/>
        );
      } else {
         return routeBuilder(subOption.children);
        }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Ah. That would be the issue. I have another recursive menuBuilder function that handles the recursive case correctly but when I created routeBuilder, the proper handling of the recursive case got lost in the translation somewhere. Simple mistake and overlooking. Thanks for the help!